# KIF alternatives for osx

Tags: macos, xcode-ui-testing, kif, kif-framework

I use **KIF** to perform iOS automated UI tests. Unfortunately it seems it is not intended to work in **OSX**. Is there any alternative for it?

**Update:**

I know there is a built-in UITest framework named XCTest for Apple applications, But I need a stronger and easier to use framework indeed.

**KIF** makes UI testing really easy and useful, with lots of great APIs that are less complex than XCTest

Answer (score 0):

Your can use XCTest, the test framework which comes built into Xcode. It is compatible with OS X, macOS, iOS and tvOS.

Comment: Yes I can, but I need a more advanced framework. Although it's possible to use built-in Xcode's test framework rather than KIF in iOS, but KIF is more advanced.

Comment: If you have specific requirements, please can you post them as requirements in the question.